# Can NHibernate string type be configured to default to AnsiString?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a database full of `varchar` values, and NHibernate is mapping `type="string"` to `nVarchar`. I know I can use `type="AnsiString"` instead of "string", but it seems like it would make a lot more sense to be able to set this at the project level, and not at the column level.

Is there any way to tell NHibernate to use `string=AnsiString` on a global basis?  I am not using Fluent nHibernate.

Update: I was asking about this because of the performance impact on queries using the indexes.  I've moved on, but I just learned today that setting the database to using a Windows collation instead of the (default but basically obsolete) SQL collations might have been a solution to my performance problem, if not my consistency issue.

Comment: If possible, try to change the datatype from varchar to nvarchar for better compatibility and it will save you lots of trouble down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Using mapping by code (from the NH core), you could do something like this:

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
// ...
var exportedTypes = assembly.GetTypes();

mapper.BeforeMapProperty += MapperOnBeforeMapProperty;

mapper.AddMappings(exportedTypes);

private void MapperOnBeforeMapProperty(
  IModelInspector modelInspector,
  PropertyPath member,
  IPropertyMapper propertyMapper)
{
  // add special handling for fields if you also
  // map fields
  PropertyInfo info = (PropertyInfo)member.LocalMember;

  if (info.PropertyType == typeof(string)
  {
    propertyMapper.Type(NHibernateUtil.AnsiString, null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use string=AnsiString system wide, you got to fixed it at the NHibernate convention level.

```
public class StringVarCharConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Property.PropertyType == typeof (string))
            instance.CustomType("AnsiString");
    }
}
```

Then you got to add this convention to the auto map configuration

```
Fluently.Configure()
.Mappings( m =>
    m.AutoMappings.Add( AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Foo>()
    .Conventions.Add< StringVarCharConvention >()))
```